# Wrong conversion of 2 dimensional array

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I'm using jersey with the default jackson mapper like so:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String classify(@HeaderParam("training") boolean training, SamplePacket sp) {
...
}
```

where sample packet looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SamplePacket {
private String id;
    private int[][] matrix;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private String label;
    private int originalMatrixSize;
```

My post data looks like this:

```
    {"id":"web-1366985890725","matrix":[[161,195,90,197,126,168,126,212],
...
[169,199,101,200,135,177,135,217]],"width":320,"height":240,"originalMatrixSize":26}
```

The problem is when I stop at a break point inside the post(classify) method the `sp` object I get includes all of the correct fields except for matrix that has the main array in the correct size but all the second dimension arrays are of zero length.

what can I do? preferably without implementing a custom mapper

Comment: You might try genson library, your matrix case should work out of box.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the default parser expects this syntax:

```
{"height":"480","id":"No31 18:29:10 24/02/2013","label":"No","matrix":
[
{"item":["349","388","279","387","315","377","314","389"]}
["349","389","279","388","315","377","314","392"]},{"item":["349","388","279","387","315","377","314","390"]},{"item":["348","386","279","387","314","376","313","389"]},{"item":["348","387","278","386","314","376","314","389"]}],"originalMatrixSize":"32","width":"640"}
```

Comment: You are then most likely not using Jackson mapper -- your original data format should work just fine with it. Rather you are using some other convention. To test this, you could create `ObjectMapper` outside of Jersey and verify stand-alone behavior; and if true, figure out why you are not using Jackson POJO mapping.